# Why is updating one variable also updating the variable assigned to it?

Tags: c, for-loop, variables, global-variables, cs50

I am getting a string from the user and storing it in a variable `plaintext`, and then I want to convert that string to lowercase in a for loop and store it in a separate variable `plaintextLowercase`. However, when I change a character in the `plaintextLowercase` variable to lowercase, the same happens in the `plaintext` variable, which I want to remain unchanged. My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void)
{
    // get_string() is a function defined in the header file cs50.h that prompts the user for string input and returns that string input
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    string plaintextLowercase = plaintext;

    //this converts the entire string to lowercase, but the issue is it is doing the same to the 'plaintext' variable as well
    //I only want the 'plaintextLowercase' string to be lowercase, while the 'plaintext' variable
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
    {
        plaintextLowercase[i] = tolower(plaintextLowercase[i]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", plaintext);
    printf("%s\n", plaintextLowercase);
}
```

Comment: <gripe>CS50 use of `string` is dumb</gripe>. It is because in CS50 land `string` is a `char *`. So `plaintext` and `plaintextLowercase` both have the same value - the address of the same character buffer containing string data. You can make a copy of the string with `string plaintextLowercase = strdup(plaintext);`. That allocates dynamic memory so don't forget to `free` it.

Comment: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @kaylum Ah thanks, I should have thought about the string datatype interfering with my code. Just for clarification, is there any reason I should use strdup() instead of strcpy()?

Comment: You can't use strcpy because you need a memory buffer to copy into. `string` is just an (uninitialised) pointer. You still need to allocate memory and assign to the pointer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a library that obfuscates basic C concepts behind useless `typedef`s and macros. If you are working with strings in C, then `char *` is the only right way to do it. Avoid using something else, specially if you are still learning how the language works. If your book/library/course is suggesting you to use opaque data types like CS50's `string`, then throw it away and go find something else to study on.

What is happening here is that your `cs50.h` header defines `string` as:

```c
typedef char * string;
```

Therefore, you are *wrongly* given the impression that doing:

```c
string a = "123";
string b = a;
```

Will somehow magically create a copy of the string. This is not the case, as the code is equivalent to:

```c
char *a = "123";
char *b = a;
```

Both `a` and `b` are pointers, and will simply end up *pointing to* the same constant string literal in memory. No copy happens.

This is the same with the result of the `get_string()` function, which dynamically allocates a string for you with [`malloc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) under the hood. So this piece of code:

```c
string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
string plaintextLowercase = plaintext;
```

has the same "issue". Your `lowercase` and `plaintextLowercase` are just two pointers to the same memory area, containing the same string. If you want to copy the string, you can use [`strdup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html):

```c
string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
string plaintextLowercase = strdup(plaintext);
```

And of course, since the new string is also dynamically allocated, do not forget to `free()` it when you don't need it anymore:

```c
free(plaintextLowercase);
```

The string allocated by `get_string()` is automatically deallocated for you at exit by the library (yet another counter-intuitive CS50 thing).

Comment: CS50's `get_string` allocates memory dynamically, but it keeps a list of allocations and frees them on exit, so explicitly `free`ing a string returned from `get_string` will give you a "double free" error.

Comment: @MOehm oh god, just when I thought I couldn't hate that thing more. Thanks.

Comment: You are a man of strong emotions. `:)` (I'm not so fond of the `string` type in CS50 either, but I can see why the writers of the course thought it would be a good idea: All the `get_something` functions are there to spare students the pitfalls with  `scanf` and get directly to the interesting stuff.)

Comment: @MOehm meh, I don't see how teaching students with `string` instead of simply `char *` is a good idea. All I keep seeing on Stack Overflow is people getting confused by those opaque typedefs and counter-intuitive functions. I do partially understand the motivations behind those library functions, but the semantics are really anti-C IMHO, you could very well have a `get_string()` function while also teaching students that you need to free the memory afterwards with a similar function (maybe even use an `atexit` handler to check for it, win-win).

Comment: @MOehm :  How/where is the memory explicitly free'd on exit?  Is there an `atexit()` call on first-use perhaps?  Seems superfluous since the system will recover all allocated memory and other resources in any case when a process terminates.   It seems a simpler solution might have been to migrate the course material to C++.

Comment: @Clifford: The code [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c) has a `teardown` function that is registered with `atexit`.

Comment: OK that explains all the former CS50 students getting really confused when in the real-world all that "magic" is not being done for them.